# Merging cells horizontally to produce a CSV file

Tags: excel, vba, merge

How do I use vba to merge the contents of 3 columns on one row into a new wworksheet with each former cell separated with a comma and the last entry in quotation marks?

e.g.

AA1 BB1 CC1 would merge to AA1,BB1,"CC1" in a new cell and the process repeats for n rows so I finish with one column containing

AA1,BB1,"CC1"
AA2,BB2,"CC2"

I've found lots of ideas to create a single column from data but not to execute a horizontal merge.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need VBA here? Doesn't simple concatenation formula `=AA1&","&BB1&","""&CC1&""""` do the job?

Comment: Agreed, simple concat' would do but I'm building this into something much larger